# Disable all the default swipe gestures in android

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am trying to build a launcher for blind in android. To avoid unwanted complexity and improve accessibility, I want to disable all the default swipe gestures and allow only clicks. 
Note: By disabling swipe gestures,  I want to avoid access to features like "[quick settings in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J2X2.jpg)" which opens when swipe down gesture, "[google now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AnEt.jpg)" which opens by swipe up gesture, etc.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?